# Pop elements out of an array using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array `results = [duplicate, otherdup]` that contains a list of duplicates

I have a regular `original_array = [duplicate, duplicate, duplicate, otherdup, otherdup, unique, unique2, unique_etc]`

How do I iterate through the `results` array (list) and Pop all but one from the original_array to look like this:

```
oringal_array = [duplicate, otherdup, unique, unique2, unique_etc]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `unique` function could look something like this:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
   var uniqueArr = [];
   var dict = {};
   for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if(!(this[i] in dict)) {
         uniqueArr.push(this[i]);
         dict[this[i]] = 1;
      }
   }

   return uniqueArr;
};
```

You could then easily do:

```
var unique_array = original_array.unique();
```

Comment: Will this work with JQuery? I notice prototype in this function

Comment: @JZ: yes, this is plain native javascript. It is true that Prototype is the name of another javascript library, but it's named so because it makes heavy use of prototyping, which is native to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I would use John Resig's Remove() method:

```
// Remove() - Completely removes item(s) from Array
// By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {

    var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
    this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
    return this.push.apply(this, rest);

};
```

You can loop through your array and just pass the index you wanted removed to the Remove() function.

Comment: Will this work with JQuery? I notice prototype in this function

Comment: Yes. jQuery is simply a JavaScript library.

Comment: My use case is a scenario where I needed to keep track of my open jQuery UI dialogs.  I stored the dialog id's in an array called `openDialogs`.  When a dialog is closed, I would get the index of the dialog in my array by using `var index = $.inArray("some-dialog-id", openDialogs);`, and then pass that to the remove() function like: `openDialogs.remove(index);`

Comment: Isn't Prototype a competing library?

Comment: Not sure, but I know that jQuery uses prototype. Just open the jQuery file and do a search for `prototype =` and you will see.

Comment: @Scott : Not even close. The 'prototype' method of the Array (et. al.) object allows you to add properties and methods to that object. Check it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_array.asp

Comment: @BryanH - I said I wasn't sure, but I know they use prototype. I didn't say Prototype.  I don't know what Prototype is, never used it.  Side note: I wouldn't use w3schools as a reference for anything. [See why here](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: `Object.prototype` is not the same as the [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) framework.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking something like this

but before calling pop you will be checking it should be popp[ed out or not by running through a loop!!

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_pop.htm